# How i can run this python+ selenium webdriver code in google chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
class TestUntitled(object):
    def __init__(self ,method):
        return self

    def test_untitled2(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.digikala.com/")
        return self

    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/Ehsan/Desktop]]/test/chromedriver.exe')
        self.method = method
        # self.vars = {}

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start with the example code on https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Then transform that code to chrome usage.
If you get that running, you have a clearer view of what is missing.

Perhaps you could provide example code in the form of a simple script, next time. That is easier for others to understand than the class you provided without the needed import statements and hints how it is called.